# Apple Pay shows Domain verification failed. Unable to access verification file on server

Tags: devops, payment, applepay, applepayjs

I am trying to verify the server domain for Apple Pay. I have placed **apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt** as per the Apple pay instruction and I can access this file with that URL as well.

But when i am going to verify the domain it shows me following Error:

**Domain verification failed. Unable to access verification file on server. Confirm that the file is in the correct location, proxies and redirects are not enabled, and the documented Apple Domain Verification IP addresses can access your server.**

I don't know what's wrong in configuration.

By the way, This Website is hosted on AWS behind Load balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wo Got solution of it:

- It sounds weird but it worked. Earlier we were using the amazon provided SSL from ACM. And Apple was not able to verify the domain because of SSL related issue. After that we taken new SSL from GoDaddy and setting up on server and it solved our issue.

Seems like Apple was not able to verify domain from the free SSL provided by the AWS.